# How to check if a NSDictionary already has a key, and then add items under that same key?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdictionary, parse-platform

I am setting up a NSDictionary object so that `NSDictionary *scoreObject` has the name of the player for its **key**, and then a mutable dictionary of `{ date : score }` for its **values**.  To get the data, I am pulling a custom class I made in Parse, which have the attributes "Name", "Score" and "createdAt".

I am trying to set up the structure so that the above could be automatically pulled across each row of data in Parse, but am running into trouble when I have two rows of data for the same `Name`, which gets set as **keys** in my `scoreObject`.  For example, if Bob has two scores and two createdAt dates, how would I be ale to simply expand the values dictionary so that both could still be stored under the key = "Bob"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code to help you. You may have to adapt something to your case:

Allocating your main dict somewhere:

```
// assuming its a property
self.scoreObject = [NSMutableDictionary new];
```

Now, whenever you will set a new pair date/score for a name, first check if that name already has any entry. If yes, use the previous allocated NSMutableDictionary to store the new pair. If not, allocate one and then set the new pair.

I'm encapsulating it in a method that receives the date and the score.

```
-(void)addNewScore:(NSString*)score AndDate:(NSString*)date forUsername:(NSString*)username
{

    NSMutableDictionary *scoresForUser = self.scoreObject[username]; //username is a string with the name of the user, e. g. @"Bob"

    if (!scoresForUser)
    {
        scoresForUser = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        self.scoreObject[username] = scoresForUser
    }

    scoresForUser[date] = score; //setting the new pair date/score in the NSMutableDictionary of scores of that giver user.

}
```

ps: I used date and score as string in the example, but you can user NSDate or NSNumber with no change if you want.

Now, you are able to list all scores of a user with something like this:

```
-(void)listScoresForUser:(NSString*)username
{
   NSMutableDictionary *scoresForUser = self.scoreObject[username];

   for (NSString *date in [scoresForUser allKeys]) {
        NSString *score = scoresForUser[date];
        NSLog(@"%@ - score: %@, createdAt: %@", username, score, date);
   }
}
```

In this way, you should be able to store the data in the structure you want. Please let me know if that is something like you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and editing your code, it worked out really well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
    NSDictionary *dict;
    //this is the dictionary you start with.  You may need to make it an NSMutableDictionary instead.


    //check if the dictionary contains the key you are going to modify.  In this example, @"Bob"
    if ([[dict allKeys] containsObject:@"Bob"]) {
        //there already is an entry for bob so we modify its entry
        NSMutableDictionary *entryDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:dict{@"Bob"}];
        [entryDict setValue:@(score) forKey:@"Date"];
        [dict setValue:entryDict forKey:@"Bob"];
    }
    else {
        //There is no entry for bob so we make a new one
        NSDictionary *entryDict = @{@"Date": @(score)};
        [dict setValue:entryDict forKey:@"Bob"];
    }
```